# Spectral radius of $T^*$ is an eigenvalue of $T^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

I need to prove the following result from Diemling's book "Nonlinear Functional Analysis"

[image]

Where K is a cone, ie, a convex closed set such that $\lambda K \subseteq K$ for all $\lambda \geq 0$ and $C \cap (-C) = \{0\}$.

I am realy stuck in proving this result with hypothesis (b), even with the hint, as I didn't manage to prove the equality of the norms and that $X_0\cap K = \emptyset$. Can you help me in these two steps?

Comment: Almost all questions where the OP pastes some image out of a book end up having something poorly defined (which was presumably introduced in earlier pages).  Here, for instance, the reader is left wondering what sort of a set is $K$.

Comment: K is a cone, ie, a convex closed set such that $\lambda K \subseteq K$ for all $\lambda \geq 0$ and $C \cap (-C) = \{0\}$. I am truly sorry !

Comment: Ok, so what does it mean to say that $K$ is normal?

Comment: K is normal if $\inf \{ ||x+y|| : x, y \in K, ||x|| = ||y|| = 1 \} > 0$